# is there a way to make python detect audio loader than a certain level db without external modules

Tags: python, audio, decibel

my science teacher has requested i make him a program to detect when his class is to load and set a timer to keep them back after school. this is great however every example i see online uses some kind of external module and nothing can be downloaded at school.

is there a way to detect sound above a specific decibel level? e.g. 60

i have successfully executed tts in this way using the `os.system()` command and powershell. my idea is to do this in a similar thing here.

the full tts program is as follows

```
import os
def say(text) :
    cmd = """
PowerShell -Command "Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Speech; (New-Object 
System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer).Speak(' """ + text + " ');"    
    os.system(cmd)

while True :
    say(input("what should i say \n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally have found no way of doing this.  I’m pretty sure You always have to use an external module to detect sounds.  Obviously your teacher will also need a microphone to run the program with its intended purpose.

Comment: he does have a mic its built into his little webcam its a usb one if that helps and can i use the source code for the modules and intergrate it into my program

Comment: Yeah, that would do it.

Comment: I I personally haven’t tried making a decibel meter on Python.  But I would assume you could use that source code in your program if it is just like any other source code...

Comment: ive never gotten any source code exept with pip (pyautogui) so have apsoloutely any idea where to go and i dont know where pip saves stuff

Comment: Pip show <package name>          should show you the location